# replace NaN with random values from a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, jupyter-notebook

I am using this code to replace NaN with random values from a range

```
import numpy as np
def processNan (x):
     return np.random.choice([1.0, 2.0])
assure['codeTypePieceIdentite'] = assure['codeTypePieceIdentite'].apply(lambda x: processNan(x) if x is nan else x)
```

its not working for some reason nothing changes

[image: result]

Comment: Use `np.nan` instead of just `nan` for the test ?

Comment: actually had to use math.isnan(x) as mentionned in the accepted answer

Comment: To write idiomatic pandas code, you should consider using `pd.isna(x)` as long as you are working on pandas objects.   See my explanations below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `math.isnan(x)` instead:

```
import numpy as np
import math
def processNan (x):
    return np.random.choice([1.0, 2.0])
assure['codeTypePieceIdentite'] = assure['codeTypePieceIdentite'].apply(lambda x: 
processNan(x) if math.isnan(x) else x)
```

Comment: @4212 alway avoid `apply` when possible, it can be really slow. This solution is basically a for-loop with a nested if-statement

Answer (score 3):

Always avoid using `.apply` when possible, it is not an optimal solution since it does not take advantage of vectorization. In this case, you can do something like this:

```
mask = df["codeTypePieceIdentite"].isna()
df.loc[mask, "codeTypePieceIdentite"] = np.random.choice([1,2], mask.sum())
```

Comment: @4212 avoiding `.apply` is also a good way of learning other pandas tools :P

Comment: hahah you got a really good point right there..c:

Answer (score 1):

To write ***idiomatic pandas code***, you should use either pandas or numpy packages as far as possible instead of Python built-in or other supplementary packages for Python.

pandas provides general function [`pd.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) and [`pd.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) for detecting missing / non-missing values for an array-like object.  Your code can be amended to use `pd.isna()` as follows:

```
assure['codeTypePieceIdentite'] = \
    assure['codeTypePieceIdentite'].apply(lambda x: processNan(x) if pd.isna(x) else x)
```

The main advantage of using pandas & numpy is that they provide efficient array processing from its ndarray data type which has been optimized for performance consideration in its base design.  numpy is also commonly used because pandas is built based on numpy.

For checking pandas Series and DataFrame for nan values, `pd.isna()` and `pd.notna()` are the obvious choice.  For checking individual elements in a pandas Series, although you can also use packages other than pandas or numpy, it is still the recommended way to use pandas functions as long as you are working on pandas objects.  This help you write *idiomatic pandas code* as well as save you some system resources (memory and processing time) on importing extra supplementary package.